# how to Dockerize Python FastAPI uvicorn application and deploy to container app

Tags: python, dockerfile, fastapi, uvicorn, azure-container-apps

[Azure Devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/azure-cosmos-db-python-and-fastapi/#comments)
as referred in above document, I'm trying to dockerize the above application and want to push to Azure container app

[GitHub repo used](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmosdb-python-fastapi)

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9
#FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7 
WORKDIR /cosmosdb-python-fastapi
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "--reload", "main:app","--host","0.0.0.0","--port", "80"]
```

not sure what’s wrong in it: while running locally its seems to be okay, but when I deploy in azure container app I can’t see the changes.

I'm expecting this Python application be deployed in Azure container app and the image should be built based on dockerfile.

Comment: i don't understand your problem ?

Comment: *"I can’t see the changes"* - I assume you mean you can't see the changes to your container when running in Azure - it seems to be running with the first version you pushed? Are you pushing with the same tag (i.e. something like `latest`) every time?